# Recover Percona Xtradb in container

Tags: mysql, docker, percona, xtradb

I have **[Percona Xtradb Cluster](https://hub.docker.com/r/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster/)** running on container.

I stopped the container and then started it.

I have error:

> 2017-02-11T13:12:00.423566Z 0 [ERROR] Found 1 prepared transactions!
>   It means that mysqld was not shut down properly last time and critical
>   recovery information (last binlog or tc.log file) was manually deleted
>   after a crash. You have to start mysqld with --tc-heuristic-recover
>   switch to commit or rollback pending transactions.
>
> 2017-02-11T13:12:00.423739Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

The message says that I need `mysqld --tc-heuristic-recover` but container stops after mysql fails to start.

**My questions are:**

- How can I fix this problem not to `run` new container but `start` existing one?
- Is there any way to make Docker container still running after main process (`mysqld`) is stopped?

Comment: Supposing your data is outside the container (ex volume), why dont you create a new container with the fix command?

Comment: No, data is inside container.

Comment: Which image are you using?

Comment: @Salem https://hub.docker.com/r/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That container uses volumes (see [here](https://github.com/Percona-Lab/percona-docker/blob/master/pxc-56/Dockerfile#L41)), so your data is not inside the container.

To find where it is stored, use `docker container inspect YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME`, and search for `Mounts` in the output. If you have `jq`installed you can use something like

```
$ docker container inspect YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME | jq ".[0].Mounts"
```

Once you found the directory where the data is stored, you should **create a backup**.

You can then create a new container, with a bind to that directory. Something like

```
$ docker run -it -v VOLUME_PATH:/var/lib/mysql OTHER_OPTIONS_HERE image_name /bin/sh
```

This should give you a shell where you can execute any commands you may need.

Once you finished, you can delete this container, and hopefully the percona one should now work.